# Heroku: Why would I be getting a H10 error after React app deployment?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

This week my computer hard drive died, I restored my app from my repository to the new hard drive, installed all the  dependencies but now my app won't work under deployment. It runs fine locally but in production it crashes. I've read many articles and threads here on SO, everything I've tried doesn't solve my problem. I've pushed the last working commit I had and that doesn't work either. I've created a support ticket on Heroku, no help from them so far. It's been two days of trying and frustration, so now I come here for some help.

**The error:**

```
2021-01-29T12:30:59.905820+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Project is running at http://172.17.191.58/
2021-01-29T12:30:59.906395+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: webpack output is served from 
2021-01-29T12:30:59.906538+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2021-01-29T12:30:59.906689+00:00 app[web.1]: [34mℹ[39m [90m｢wds｣[39m: 404s will fallback to /
2021-01-29T12:30:59.907032+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2021-01-29T12:30:59.907032+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-29T12:31:00.092835+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-01-29T12:31:00.133082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-29T12:31:02.023244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.myapp.com request_id=7bcd9236-6d02-4c9b-bf0c-7d18dce36830 fwd="187.65.182.161" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "client",
"homepage": "/",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@ctrl/tinycolor": "^3.1.6",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.10.0",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^1.8.6",
    "async": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "ckeditor": "^4.12.1",
    "ckeditor4": "^4.15.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "filestack-js": "^0.11.5",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "grapesjs": "^0.16.34",
    "grapesjs-blocks-flexbox": "^0.1.1",
    "grapesjs-lory-slider": "^0.1.5",
    "grapesjs-parser-postcss": "^0.1.1",
    "grapesjs-plugin-ckeditor": "0.0.10",
    "grapesjs-style-bg": "^1.0.3",
    "grapesjs-style-filter": "^0.1.3",
    "grapesjs-style-gradient": "^2.0.3",
    "grapick": "^0.1.9",
    "intro.js": "^3.1.0",
    "intro.js-react": "^0.2.0",
    "jimp": "^0.14.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^11.0.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^4.1.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.11.1",
    "react-color": "^2.18.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.2.1",
    "react-favicon": "0.0.17",
    "react-firebase-file-uploader": "^2.4.3",
    "react-firebaseui": "^4.1.0",
    "react-google-autocomplete": "^1.1.3",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-iframe": "^1.8.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-instafeed": "^1.0.0",
    "react-meta-tags": "^0.7.4",
    "react-number-format": "^4.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^4.5.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-toastify": "^5.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "spectrum-colorpicker": "^1.8.1",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.1",
    "wowjs": "^1.1.3"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start --env.ENVIRONMENT=production",
    "dev": "react-scripts start --env.ENVIRONMENT=development",
    "build": "set \"HTTPS=true\" && react-scripts build --env.ENVIRONMENT=production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "patch-package",
    "deploy": "git push heroku master",
    "clean-cache": "heroku builds:cache:purge"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
    ]
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16"
}
}
```

**Node & NPM versions:**

```
user@beast$ npm -v
6.14.10
user@beast$ node -v
v14.15.4
```

I'm out of ideas at this point. I've pushed over 30 new versions into Heroku thus far, any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: Note you shouldn't be using the dev server in production. Serve the build output from a proper server.

Comment: You mean `serve -s build`? I've tried using `serve` too. Also package.json hasn't changed when I had it working before my hard drive crashed. But I understand your point, I'll try that now. Thanks.

Comment: When I serve it locally I get `�` and in the console it says `The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.` However, I do have the HTML meta tag `charset=utf-8"`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work! :)))))) Every single time when I ran out of ideas and post a question here, even after days of trial and errors, somehow I arrive to a solution.

Basically my solution was debugging it properly.

With **@jonrsharpe** suggestion about serving it from a proper server, I tried running it locally by running `serve -s -d build` and this gave me a proper error details. I was getting gibberish on the browser, and the server output showed a TLS handshake error (HTTPS), which is understandable since I am running it locally. So all I did was remove `set \"HTTPS=true\"` from the `package.json[scripts.build]` and included `package.json[scripts.start] : "serve -s build"`.

My final `package.json`:

```
{
    [...],

    "scripts": {
        "start": "serve -s build",
        "dev": "react-scripts start --env.ENVIRONMENT=development",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "postinstall": "patch-package",
        "deploy": "git push heroku master",
        "clean-cache": "heroku builds:cache:purge -a myapp"
    },

    [...]
}
```

I swear I had tried serve it using `serve -s build`. Two things I did different, I installed `certbot (LetsEncrypt)` locally (I was going to set up SSL certificates locally to debug it further but I got it to work in the production server as I was setting this up.) And the other thing was removing `set \"HTTPS=true\"` as mentioned already. So I am not completely sure what did it.

I added back `set \"HTTPS=true\"` to `package.json` but the app isn't redirecting to HTTPS anymore... but that's fine and minor, at least right now I can deploy it.